# "runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x129000a0 overflowed to 0x12900088"

Tags: c++

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<string> v;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        string temp;
        cin>>temp;
        v.push_back(temp);

        //if(v.size() == 1)
        //{
        //    continue;
        //}

        //cout << i << endl;
        //cout << endl;

        //cout << v.size();

        int k = i;
        while(v[k-1].length() > v[k].length() && k>-1)
        {
            swap(v[k], v[k-1]);

            k--;
        }
        //cout << endl;
    }

    bool check = true;
    for(int i=0; i<v.size()-1; i++)
    {
        //cout << v[i] << endl;
        //cout << v[i+1] << endl;

        if (v[i+1].find(v[i]) != std::string::npos)
        {
            //std::cout << "found!" << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        //cout << "false" << endl;
        check = false;
    }

    if(check == true)
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cout << v[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
}
```

What’s the reason for this error?

The **input** was:

```
100
npugmvzdgfnzyxuyfwbzwktiylhvhwgeqauolidpnbemhgbunpefzsltewkxdcrzxgvmkb
bezfumiguzafxghvcfqmwpopxvazctlftelveayycypjckooxeehyk
ingenqhogs
elhnhxjwrytbmmqdwwrivvljybhnwfgwhvdgjqgqgvunuemdtrgpyvaanovheqbupamzrjxh
rpvktlmyxfshahfgunrhuqtosysymfjruqlzdooauuihtchzqgyrhcoxbtoorkxkwakvdkiakitlqfbgz
tnrnpghjmqumbzfnztiijgwkiygyfevfebuammkwnoinqvhhlsuoqtfkazqhlnuqtthudhhovjqiuykwqtck
mloehzniuwyakgwmopfgknpoiuiyewijmoefjjjsdimkisugehwqefcx
tthmaxtahimxxts
fspoetalxgcgowhjtanerjpqnen
hefsyokneekdgpbicss
```

It works for other cases.

> Diagnostics detected issues [cpp.clang++-diagnose]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\vector:1802:11: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x129000a0 overflowed to 0x12900088

> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\vector:1802:11 in

Comment: Unrelated: `#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>` suggests that you don't know what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does. This is a good thing because we can nip it in the bud. Give [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) a read.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Whats the reason for this error:

You set `i` to `0`

```
int i=0;
```

Then you set `k` to `0`.

```
int k=i;
```

Then you use **`k-1`** to index `std::vector<std::string> v`.

```
while(v[k-1].length()
```

`k-1` is `-1`, but it gets worse.  `std::vector::operator[]` casts the parameter to an `unsigned` type, producing an **impossibly huge, not-at-all-valid index**.

[No bounds checking is performed with `std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) and you end up treating memory you don't own as if it were a validly constructed `std::string`.